# How can I import a GIS dataset in arcGRID format?

Tags: import, geography

A dataset on global aridity is published here http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/global-aridity-and-pet-database. It's a global raster on a 10 arcsecond, so fine grained, finer than I need.

Mathematica's documentation illustrates exactly what to do with the zipped download, but when I try the same here, I get these:

> LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link  LinkObject['/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/GDAL.exe',1755,13].
>
> Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as ArcGRID format.

Any hints?

A hardcopy of my novel is a gift to whomever solves this for me.